# Register two .tif images in Imagej, align z-axis and rotation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, imagej

I am working with Fiji on my image analysis.

I have two *.tif stacks from a microscopic sample, one of them is slightly rotated and has a z-axis offset. It's like a screw being screwed in to a different amount than the first one.

How can I align both stacks so that the rotation and the z-axis offset is evened out? Is Fiji / Imagej the right program for that? Do I need a plugin?

Thanks already in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try MultiStackReg, which is based on the StackReg and TurboReg plugins:

http://bradbusse.net/downloads.html